# How to write Firefox plugin with C# and mono?

Tags: c#, firefox, mono, xpcom

this question was asked many times:

- 2004

  - http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2004-October/008213.html
- 2005

  - http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/0SAXwxPyVBCC31hdB3Mm
  - http://codeverge.com/netscape.mozilla.jseng/xpcom-and-mono-or-just-c/1577232
- 2007

  - http://forum.mozilla-russia.org/viewtopic.php?id=17385
  - http://rsdn.ru/forum/cpp.applied/2514021.flat
- 2009

  - http://ru-csharp.livejournal.com/153546.html
- 2010

  - https://forums.mozilla.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1445
  - https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/5069566

and always without answers...

Language bindings page doesn't contain C# or mono (but does so for Java and Python):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings

There is some code - http://off.net/~shaver/mono/

But i don't see C++ part of it (and I think it is necessary as a "XPCOM Component Loader")

There is also something what is called MonoConnect

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=296672

But i didn't found it's docs in google.

I know that it is possible to implement plugin as CLR host as written here:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/

but i don't want to reinvent the wheel,

that is why I am asking where to find an existing implementation of "Component Loader".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer: http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2004-October/008215.html, first answer in your first link to a mailing list.

Here is a [github link](https://github.com/jrmuizel/mozilla-cvs-history/tree/master/extensions/mono/src) to the issue in MonoConnect. I just took some strings in the diff which is in the tracker(the link you provided) and searched in google for it, got a github repo.

As well as this: http://people.mozilla.org/~chofmann/l10n/tree/mozilla/extensions/mono/

As far as written code, this is the most you will probably get.